# Parsing json containing array of array gives 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I am trying to access elements inside an array of the array in JSON but I am getting `undefined`.

> Error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lsi_short_name' of undefined at line no. 9 $("#jsondata").append(

Code is shown below :

```
var data = '{"response":[[{"1":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"A","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"2":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"B","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"4":{"type":"d","lsi_short_name":"D","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"5":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"E","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}], [{"1":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"A","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"2":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"B","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"4":{"type":"d","lsi_short_name":"D","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"6":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"F","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}]]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);

for(i=0;i<obj.response.length;i++) {
    for (j=0; j < obj.response[i].length; j++) {
        $("#jsondata").append("<li onclick=jsonDetails('"+obj.response[i][j][j+1]['lsi_short_name'] +"','"+ obj.response[i][j][j+1]['entities']+"','"+ obj.response[i][j][j+1]['attributes']+"')>"+obj.response[i][j][j+1]['lsi_short_name']+"</li>");  
    }
    $("#jsondata").append("<br>");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jaromanda But its showing results for all elements except 2 element onwards for 2nd array

Comment: You need to capture the element before starting the inner for loop.

Comment: ok ... just realised you do ... but your loop looks wrong

Comment: oh, I see, there's a OBJECT with numeric keys in there, it isn't an array

Comment: index 0 has a object with key 1 - so [j][j+1] will work, similarly with index 1 has an object with key 2. But index 2 has an object with key 4, and 3 has 5 ... they are plus to ... that's in results[0] ... in results[1] your objects have keys 1,2,4,6 ... again the first two will work, but the last two wont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You key order is not serial wise, that's why you should not use `j+1`. So you can get the exact key first using `Object.keys()` then access the properties: Example:

```
var data = '{"response":[[{"1":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"A","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"2":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"B","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"4":{"type":"d","lsi_short_name":"D","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"5":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"E","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}], [{"1":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"A","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"2":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"B","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"4":{"type":"d","lsi_short_name":"D","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"6":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"F","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}]]}';
//var data = '{"response": "[[{"1": {"attributes": [], "entities": [], "lsi_short_name": "a", "type": "process"}}, {"2": {"attributes": ["d"], "entities": ["c"], "lsi_short_name": "b", "type": "process"}}], [{"1": {"attributes": [], "entities": [], "lsi_short_name": "a", "type": "process"}},{"6": {"attributes": [], "entities": [], "lsi_short_name": "f", "type": "process"}}]]"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(data);
for(var i = 0; i < obj.response.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < obj.response[i].length; j++) {
        var key = Object.keys(obj.response[i][j])[0];
        $("#jsondata").append("<li onclick=jsonDetails('" + obj.response[i][j][key]['lsi_short_name'] +"','"+ obj.response[i][j][key]['entities']+"','"+ obj.response[i][j][key]['attributes']+"')>"+obj.response[i][j][key]['lsi_short_name']+"</li>");
    }
    $("#jsondata").append("<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the object beyond the length of the array. You also do not have any property named *attributes*.

You can first get the values from the object then use the index like the following way:

```js
var data = '{"response":[[{"1":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"A","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"2":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"B","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"4":{"type":"d","lsi_short_name":"D","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"5":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"E","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}], [{"1":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"A","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"2":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"B","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"4":{"type":"d","lsi_short_name":"D","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}, {"6":{"type":"p","lsi_short_name":"F","entities":["term_Quantity"]}}]]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(data);
for(let i=0;i<obj.response.length;i++){  
  for (let j=0; j < obj.response[i].length; j++) {
  let o = Object.values(obj.response[i][j])[0];
  $("#jsondata").append("<li onclick=jsonDetails('"+o['lsi_short_name'] +"','"+ o['entities'][0]+"')>"+o['lsi_short_name']+"</li>");
  }
  $("#jsondata").append("<br>");
}

function jsonDetails(sn, en){
  console.log(sn + '::' + en)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jsondata"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should look like below:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
for(i=0;i<obj.response.length;i++){
    var x = obj.response[i];
    for (j=0; j < x.length; j++) {    
       //Assuming the keys are serial else you need to get all the keys using Object.keys method.
       var keyName = (j+1).toString();
       //Access various prop of your json like this -->    x[j][keyName]["lsi_short_name"]
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error at x.length - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: try with var x = obj.response[i];   (updated my code above)